# Fitting a line to qqplot with two datasets in r

Tags: r, plot, distribution

I have two datasets and I used the qqplot function in r to compare their distributions. I would like to fit a line through the plot but the qqline function is not appropriate since we have two datasets. Any idea on what I can use please?

```
x <- rnorm(10000, 12, 3) 
y<- rnorm(10000, 18, 5)
qqplot(x,y)
abline(lm(y~x))
```

Comment: Could you post some same code of what you've tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that a qqplot of `x` versus `y` is just the same as `plot(sort(x), sort(y))` :

```r
x <- rnorm(10000, 12, 3) 
y <- rnorm(10000, 18, 5)

qqplot(x, y)
```

[image]

```r
plot(sort(x), sort(y))
```

[image]

The problem in your example is that you are trying to add the regression line for y on x, but not the *sorted* versions of x and y. Effectively, you are plotting the regression line for this:

```r
plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Which, not surprisingly, is an almost perfectly flat line with an intercept equal to the mean of y.

Instead, you can regress the *sorted* y and the *sorted* x to get the regression line for the qqplot:

```r
x <- rnorm(10000, 12, 3) 
y <- rnorm(10000, 18, 5)

qqplot(x, y)
abline(lm(sort(y) ~ sort(x)), col = "red", lwd = 2, lty = 2)
```

[image]